# Collecting NSXMLDocument warning output

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nserror, nsxml, nsxmldocument

I have the following helper function for transforming XML via XSLT:

```
- (NSXMLDocument *)transform:(NSString *)xml :(NSString *)xslt
{
    NSError *xmlDocErr = nil;
    NSXMLDocument *transformedXmlDoc = nil;
    
    NSXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc]
                              initWithXMLString:xml
                              options:NSXMLDocumentValidate
                              error:&xmlDocErr];
    
    if (xmlDocErr) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [xmlDocErr localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        transformedXmlDoc = [xmlDoc objectByApplyingXSLTString:xslt 
                                    arguments:nil
                                    error:&xmlDocErr];
        if (xmlDocErr) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [xmlDocErr localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    return transformedXmlDoc;
}
```

It works as expected, but there's a slight quirk I could use assistance with.

When I try to use an XSLT function that's unknown to NSXMLDocument (say, [EXSLT](http://www.exslt.org/)'s [`node-set()`](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html)), I get output in Xcode similar to the below - the first line, in particular, is of interest:

> xmlXPathCompOpEval: function node-set not found
>
> XPath error: Unregistered function runtime
>
> error: element for-each
>
> Failed to evaluate the 'select' expression.

That's cool; it's exactly what I'd expect.

The interesting thing to me, however, is that the output doesn't contain `"Error: "` anywhere (which should be the case if that output had been captured by my `[xmlDocErr localizedDescription]` calls).

**So, here's the question:** how can I grab the above output (so that I can use it for displaying relevant messages to my user)?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening deep within `libxml`, on line 13479 of [`xpath.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libxml2/libxml2-22.3/libxml2/xpath.c?txt), which ends up calling `xmlGenericErrorDefaultFunc()` on line 71 of [`error.c`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libxml2/libxml2-22.3/libxml2/error.c?txt), which prints to `stderr`. So the easiest way to do this is to capture `stderr` while the XSLT processing is going on:

```
- (NSXMLDocument *)transform:(NSString *)xml :(NSString *)xslt
{
    NSError *xmlDocErr = nil;
    NSXMLDocument *transformedXmlDoc = nil;

    NSXMLDocument *xmlDoc = [[NSXMLDocument alloc]
                             initWithXMLString:xml
                             options:NSXMLDocumentValidate
                             error:&xmlDocErr];

    if (xmlDocErr) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [xmlDocErr localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        // Pipe for stderr
        NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
        // Duplicate of stderr (will use later)
        int cntl = fcntl(STDERR_FILENO,F_DUPFD);
        // Redirect stderr through our pipe
        dup2([[pipe fileHandleForWriting] fileDescriptor], STDERR_FILENO);

        transformedXmlDoc = [xmlDoc objectByApplyingXSLTString:xslt
                                                     arguments:nil
                                                         error:&xmlDocErr];
        // Get the data
        NSData *dat = [[pipe fileHandleForReading] availableData];
        // Redirect stderr through our duplicate, to restore default output behavior
        dup2(cntl, STDERR_FILENO);
        // Did anything get logged?
        if ([dat length]>0) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dat encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
        }
        if (xmlDocErr) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", [xmlDocErr localizedDescription]);
        }
    }

    return transformedXmlDoc;
}
```

But this is a bit of a hack, so be careful...

If you aren't satisfied with that solution, it should be possible to override the variable `xmlGenericError` (which, by default, references `xmlGenericErrorDefaultFunc`) with a custom error-handling function of your own using `initGenericErrorDefaultFunc` on line 864 of [`xmlerror.h`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libxml2/libxml2-22.3/libxml2/include/libxml/xmlerror.h?txt). That would be a lot safer, but also more complicated (if it's possible at all).

Comment: Fantastic, @SimonM - thanks for doing this digging. I'll play around and see what I come up with.